# Not able to submit Form using PHP and Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I know it has been asked before, but I haven't found anything that works.

Basically, my form isn't submitting. At all. So I can't even figure out if the values are wrong because I can't get out of the modal/form.

I'm using bootstrap/php for this. Compared to my other code using the exact same process (with a different context, of course) it seems that it should work. I've tried to check the names to avoid duplicates as well as unset any session/post variables that might have been used.

Maybe more eyes will yield more success!

```
<form id="addSession" action="" method="post">
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" name="sessionID" value="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="createSession"/>
                <label>Select Start Date:</label>
                <select name="startDate">
                    <option value="<? echo($currDateValue); ?>" selected="selected"><? echo($currDateDisplay); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; ++$i) {
                            echo('<option value="' . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($currDateValue . '+' . $i . (($i == 1) ? ' day' : ' days'))) . '">' 
                                                   . date('D, M d, Y', strtotime($currDateDisplay . '+' . $i . (($i == 1) ? ' day' : ' days'))) . '</option>');
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <label>Select End Date:</label>
                <select name="endDate">
                    <option value="<? echo(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($currDateValue . '+1 day'))); ?>" selected="selected"><? echo(date('D, M d, Y', strtotime($currDateDisplay . '+1 day'))); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        for ($i = 2; $i <= 16; ++$i) {
                            echo('<option value="' . date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($currDateValue . '+' . $i . (($i == 1) ? ' day' : ' days'))) . '">'
                                                   . date ('D, M d, Y', strtotime($currDateDisplay . '+' . $i . (($i == 1) ? ' day' : ' days'))) . '</option>');
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Session</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Edit: Thanks for the replies! All of the replies given are well appreciated, but the following code works (and is written in the same manner as the code that doesn't work)

```
<div id="addPointsModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addPointsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Adding Points To <? echo($data['real_name']); ?></h3>
    </div>
    <form id="addPointsToStudent" action="" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Enter Point Value:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addPointsMonoStudent" placeholder="0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="studentUID" value="<? echo($uid); ?>"/>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Points</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So I'm not quite sure whats going on!

Comment: Try changing the button to a `input type="submit"` instead of a button

Comment: Isn't it because of your action parameter that is empty ? You need to fill it with the destination page, except if you're handling it with JavaScript.

Comment: @jerska if the action is empty it will be send back to the same url

Comment: @Perry Didn't know that ! Then edward's answer should be the right one.

Comment: @jerska, you can also submit a form with the button tag :)

Comment: i recommend ajax & jquery

Comment: @Gracchus For just submitting a form ?

Comment: @Jerska for everything until php somehow gets websockets.  when i was doing 100% ajax php, i had almost no server-side lines, and jquery keeps the client-side down to a minimum, not to mention it's nice to not have to reload the entire site anytime you want to interact with the server.

Comment: Have you tried this code on a bare empty page? so that none of your other javascripts blocking the submission? Can you also check the console to see if there were any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `<form>` tags within the `<div class="modal-body">` div.  I'm not sure that Bootstrap is pulling that portion of your code when creating the modal view.

I also see that the submit button is in the footer portion.  Try adding the entirety of the form to the modal-body as a test to see if you can at least get the form to submit that way.

Comment: I've edited the OP with code that suggests that this method wouldn't make a difference. I tried it and it certainly didn't =(

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue too. The problem could cause by the JavaScript

When I delete the  it works

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, try changing button to input, you can't submit a form using `<button>`

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send form" />
```